# Linq comparing two list - learning linq

Tags: linq, list, loops, compare

I recently started learning LINQ. Bsically to understand this technology better I try to rewrite some of my previous programs using LINQ. I mean I try to replace foreach methods etc with linq queries.

Today I encounterd a problem.
I have a list of objects element

```
  List<Element> elementList 
 public  class Element
    {
        private string Id;
        private List<Element> consequentElementsList;


    }
```

List of elements contains all elements which are placed on form. Each element has a List of consequtive elements. 
I need to find all predecessors element of element I've chosen.
Is there any way to do this in LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var element = // a single element
var query = from e in elementList
            where e.consequentElementsList.Any(ce => ce.Id == element.Id)
            select e;
```

It retrieves each element from the element list where the consequent element list contains any element matching the ID you've selected.

Of course, I've ignored the fact that `Id` and `consequentElementsList` is private in your example.